# Change of limits when using squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, proof-writing, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to evaluate
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor 
$$One step in the proof involved writing $n=1/x$ and using the inequalities:

$$
\frac{n}{n+1} < -x\left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor \leq \frac{n+1}{n}
$$By the squeeze theorem,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(-x \left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+1}{n}  = 1
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \qquad \lim_{x \to 0^+} x \left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor = -1
$$

According to the solution above when $x \to 0^{+}$  then  $n \to \infty$. Why is this the case here?

Comment: What is $E(.)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici   the greatest integer function.